# Firebase 3.0 Auth Facebook Internal error?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using their sample code quickstart-js customized to my project and using Firebase serve (to serve the html files).

API dies on:

> POST
>   "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=AIzaSyCz6fP-li-ItWfSN-m7Oj-6VOFydWEn8jg"
>
> facebook-popup.html:83

```
{code: "auth/internal-error", message: "An internal error has occurred.}
```

Anyone having success with Facebook login?  [Twitter fails the same way]
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable and configure Facebook and Twitter providers for your project in the Firebase console.

Comment: Yes.  Of course.  Everything was working fine with Firebase 2.  It looks to me like Google Identitytookit is broken at the moment.

Comment: Did you migrate from an existing Firebase 2.x project?

Comment: yes.  Would samples work if I were to create a new project?

Comment: Unfortunately, there were migration problems that were detected and currently being worked on. I suggest creating a new project for now until the other migration issues are resolved.

Comment: But this may not be a trivial thing to do since you would  loose your current users...